# How to setup squid-deb-proxy and squid-deb-proxy-client to be more autonomous (to work without internet)?

Tags: networking, apt, server, updates, proxy

I have server with installed `squid-deb-proxy`. Let's say that its IP is 10.13.3.7.
I have installed `squid-deb-proxy-client` on other machines (let's name them clients). Server and clients are in the same network and run Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS.

The repositories to be mirrored are correctly defined in `/etc/squid-deb-proxy/mirror-dstdomain.acl` to suite clients requirements:

```
archive.canonical.com
archive.ubuntu.com
changelogs.ubuntu.com
cloud.r-project.org
ddebs.ubuntu.com
deb.opera.com
dl.google.com
dl.winehq.org
download.opensuse.org
downloads.sourceforge.net
download.virtualbox.org
extras.ubuntu.com
mirrors.ubuntu.com
ports.ubuntu.com
ppa.launchpad.net
private-ppa.launchpad.net
ru.archive.ubuntu.com
security.ubuntu.com
typora.io
```

All clients have the same list of repositories.

The server is working normally - I see both `TCP_MEM_HIT/200` and `TCP_HIT/200` in `/var/log/squid-deb-proxy/access.log` on the request of deb-packages.

Yesterday night I have downloaded all updates from one of the clients (ran `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`). So I expect that Squid Deb cache is filled with headers and packages.

On today morning there is no internet because of WAN (ISP) maintenance. I can't ping anything outside the LAN. I can ping 10.13.3.7 from clients.

Thus when I run `sudo apt update` on clients I see the following messages:

> 0% [Working]
>   0% [Waiting for headers]
>   Err:N http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu *release* InRelease
>      Connection failed [IP: 10.13.3.7 8000]
>   ...
>   W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/*release*/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 10.13.3.7 8000]
>   ...
>   W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

and same for `sudo apt upgrade` or `sudo apt install ...`:

> 0% [Waiting for headers]
>   Err:N http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/*pocket* *arch* *name* *arch* *version*
>    Connection failed [IP: 10.13.3.7 8000]
>   E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/....deb  Connection failed [IP: 10.13.3.7 8000]
>   E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Is it possible to work without internet and get packages from local `squid-deb-proxy` cache?

**Update:** setting `offline_mode on` in `/etc/squid3/squid.conf` does not help - I get *503 service unavailable* errors for some objects during `apt-get update`. Moreover this options prevents cache update if I have internet access on the server.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work without an Internet connection if the specific .deb package that your client is trying to fetch is in a repository that wasn't cached before. Could also be new dependencies that needs fetching. You should be able to check this file `/etc/squid-deb-proxy/mirror-dstdomain.acl` for cached repos/domains.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I have already set up correct (and same) repositories on client and server. So both the *sources.list* and *mirror-dstdomain.acl* are correctly defined in correspondence of each other.

Comment: While package files are cached the meta data is probably not ... it gets an extra http header from the upstream servers to prevent that. `Cache-Control: max-age=0, proxy-revalidate`.